# Graph Theory, Using Euler's Formula

Tags: graph-theory

A regular polyhedron is a polyhedron in which every face is bounded by the same number of edges, and every vertex has the same number of incident edges. Every polyhedron can be associated naturally to a planar graph - one which has the same vertex, edge, and face structure. Use Euler’s formula on this planar graph to show that there are only 5 regular polyhedra!

So I've taken an advanced geometry class before, so I already know what the answer is, but I'm having difficulty applying graph theory to it.

Comment: Given a regular polyhedron, how you might associate it with a planar graph?

Comment: Can you count the edges in different ways and then combine formulas? That's the graph theory technique that comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euler's formula is:
$$n+f=m+2$$
where:
$n$ is number of vertices, $m$ is number of edges, and $f$ is number of faces.

Because every of faces is polyhedron having $a$ angles, and every edge lies between two faces, we have:
$$f\cdot a = 2m$$

And because every vertex has $r$ edges, and every edge connects two vertices, we have $$n\cdot r = 2m$$

We can use these in Euler's formula:
$$\frac{2m}{a}+\frac{2m}{r}=m+2$$
which leads to:
$$(r-2)(a-2) < 4$$

Since $a\geq3$ and $r\geq3$ and $a,\,r\in\mathbb{N}$, it's pretty easy to solve above just by testing all possible values, which gives following result (as pairs $(r,\,a)$):
$(5,\,3),\,(3,\,5),\,(3,\,4),\,(4,\,3),\,(3,\,3)$.